# Header problems with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, header, footer

hi guys i need some help since im new with jquery.

Im using jquery to load something in a div. Here is my code

```
$('.menu_top').click(function(){

    var href = $(this).attr('href');

    $('#main_section').hide().load(href).slideDown("normal");

    //slideDown("normal");
    //fadeIn("normal");
    //fadeToggle("slow", "swing");

    return false;
});
```

Everything works fine

I also have my php pages divided into pieces like header.php, footer.php etc.

The problem comes when i try to sent a post data to the same page, for example post from home.php to home.php. The headers and footers just dissapear.

I've tried to use stuff like

```
if(isset and !empty){
  //put the headers
}
```

But that didnt work....

Thanks for the help

Comment: are you trying to post data to a page via ajax?

Comment: No, im posting my data with php

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for `$_POST`:

```
if(isset($_POST['your_post_value'])){
// the POST value exists
}
```

Comment: @AldoOlivares You are going to want to do the `POST` checks after the inclusion of your header files.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#main_section').hide().load(href, function() { $(this).slideDown("normal"); });
```

The 2nd argument to .load is the handler that should be called when the loading has finished. Then you slideDown